# Minecraft Forge mod making gradlew build not working

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, minecraft-forge

When I run the command "gradlew build" in my mods folder it returns "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" and when i open the folder build/libs i get two files one NAME-VER.jar and one NAME-VER--sources.jar so i copied   NAME-VER.jar into my minecraft mod folder and the game starts okay but in minecraft all i get is "mercuries_updater"
could it be to do with build.gradle file?
Info: Windows10, eclipse ide, Minecraft 1.11.2, ForgeGradle 2.2-SNAPSHOT-d13a6c8

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You must build using `gradlew build`, Eclipse doesn't know about the reobfuscation task and as such, anything that Eclipse compiles (without using Gradle) will fail.
2. The two output files in your build/libs folder are:

   1. The compiled jar file (your mod that you will distribute).
   2. The *source files* jar, which you do not need to do anything with. This file will not run correctly when put in the Minecraft mods folder.

I am not sure why your mod is not showing up properly when you add the jar file to the mods folder, I would need to see the Forge log from that attempt.

Comment: it still does not work when i put that one file into minecraft under mods it says mercuries_updater not my own mod name  like when i press run name.Client in Eclipses also i setup Eclipse with gradle so it does not use the normal Eclipse when compiling both ways dont work anyway

Comment: im using the buildship gradle extension that the ide came with im not sure what log to give you as it works from run in Eclipse just that would not give me a jar file

Comment: @projectuser I need the *Forge* log (`latest.log`) when you put the jar in the Minecraft mods folder *after building.*

Comment: in the log it loads the mod file but thats it sorry i dont want to shere it

Comment: @projectuser Then I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by moving source folders into
`src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`